# ping works but tracert reaches the max 30 hops

Tags: vmware

I have 4 guests in my VMware host, all of them work as expected; but if I use tracert to find out the route they take to reach the external site, all of them will reach the max 30 hops after the first hop is the gateway:

```
[root@cdsw ~]# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=9.51 ms

[root@cdsw ~]# /usr/bin/traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (192.168.122.2)  0.118 ms  0.080 ms  0.062 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Can anyone enlighten me why and how can I get the full route?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Looks like hop 2 is blocking ICMP (due to a firewall or other security measures). You might get better results with running Linux traceroute which uses UDP.

Comment: Thanks but don't know what you mean here: the test was done from the guest which is a centos.

Comment: Regardless, something sitting at hop 2 is blocking traceroute.

Comment: You can use tcp or udp traceroute like: `traceroute -T 8.8.8.8` or `traceroute -U 8.8.8.8`

Comment: ahha, Thank you for that trick, I will test it out after work.